# Error while working on the site in Django, part 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, debugging, error-handling

This is a continuation of the previous question. When I continued to work on the site and when I wanted to test the site through "python manage.py runserver" in the C:\mysite\site\miniproject directory, the following error pops up:

```
C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py:321: RuntimeWarning: Model 'blog.post' was already registered. Reloading models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most notably with related models.
  new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py:321: RuntimeWarning: Model 'blog.post' was already registered. Reloading models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most notably with related models.
  new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 423, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 416, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 602, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 595, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\mysite\site\miniproject\miniproject\urls.py", line 43

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Here is a link to the chapter where I worked: https://pocoz.gitbooks.io/django-v-primerah/content/sozdanie-shablonov-dlia-view.html , Most likely I made a mistake somewhere. Next, I will show you the contents of the files:

```
base.html:
{% load static files %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static "css/blog.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {%endblock%}
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <h2>My blog</h2>
    <p>This is my blog.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

list.html:
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>My Blog</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h2>
            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </h2>
        <p class="date">
            Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
        </p>
        {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
    {% endfor %}
{%endblock%}

detail.html:
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ post. title }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <p class="date">
        Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
    </p>
{{ post.body|linebreaks}}
{%endblock%}

C:\mysite\site\miniproject\blog\views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                                   status='published',
                                   publish_year=year,
                                   publish__month=month,
                                   publish_day=day)
    return render(request,'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post})

# Create your views here.

C:\mysite\site\miniproject\blog\urls.py:
from django.conf.urls import url
from. import views

urlpatterns = [
    # post views
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'\
        r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.post_detail,
        name='post_detail'),
]

C:\mysite\site\miniproject\miniproject\urls.py:
"""miniproject URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

def include(arg, namespace=None):
    app_name = None
    if isinstance(arg, tuple):
        # Callable returning a namespace hint.
        try:
            urlconf_module, app_name = arg
        except ValueError:
            if namespace:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                    "Cannot override the namespace for a dynamic module that "
                    "provides a namespace."
                )
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "Passing a %d-tuple to include() is not supported. Pass a "
                "2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name, and "
                "provide the namespace argument to include() instead." % len(arg)
            )
    else:
        # No namespace hint - use manually provided namespace.
        urlconf_module = arg

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', "blog",  namespace='blog')),
]
C:\mysite\site\miniproject\blog\models.py:
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import reverse
class Post(models.Model):
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                        args=[self.publish.year,
                              self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                              self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                              self.slug])

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publish',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


# Create your models here.
```

I did what the users said from the previous question([Error while working on the site in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74645823/error-while-working-on-the-site-in-django) ), but it didn't help, maybe I didn't install all the libraries or made a typo

Comment: Yes, a typo.  You forgot a `]` at the end of your **urls.py**.  After `url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', "blog",  namespace='blog'),`.

Comment: @raphael  I fixed the code, but there is an error                                                                                      File "C:\mysite\site\miniproject\miniproject\urls.py", line 43
    ]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is just another typo.  You need a closing parenthesis for the **url** function, and another to close the **include** function:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', "blog",  namespace='blog')),
]
```

Syntax errors could be avoided by using a good code editor.  For example, I use [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (FREE) and *sometimes* I can easily see the syntax error just by looking at the colors (for example one url is blue, the other white, when they should be the same color).  There are other good code editors out there that are free.

**EDIT**
This is an old way of [Passing a 3-tuple or an app_name to include()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/1.9/#passing-a-3-tuple-or-an-app-name-to-include), which is deprecated. The newer method is to replace the code I have above with:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls',  namespace='blog')),
]
```

I also notices that you have this in your code:

```py
def include(arg, namespace=None):
    app_name = None
    if isinstance(arg, tuple):
        # Callable returning a namespace hint.
        try:
            urlconf_module, app_name = arg
        except ValueError:
            if namespace:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                    "Cannot override the namespace for a dynamic module that "
                    "provides a namespace."
                )
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "Passing a %d-tuple to include() is not supported. Pass a "
                "2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name, and "
                "provide the namespace argument to include() instead." % len(arg)
            )
    else:
        # No namespace hint - use manually provided namespace.
        urlconf_module = arg
```

WHY?  This is part of Django source code.  When you write:
`from django.conf.urls import include, url`
The function `def include...` is imported into your code, you do not need to write it in yourself.  Which also means you can remove
`from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured`

Since all these changes are getting complicated, below is what your final code should look like for your **C:\mysite\site\miniproject\miniproject\urls.py:**:

```py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls',  namespace='blog')),
]
```

But this is still using features that are likely to be deprecated in Django.  Instead of **url** use **path**:

**FINAL CODE**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    path(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls',  namespace='blog')),
]
```

**Summary**
You are obviously using a tutorial from several years ago using many features that are, or will be deprecated (no longer used) in Django.  A strong suggestion would be to find a more updated, recent tutorial.

Comment: I fixed the code, but there is an error File "C:\mysite\site\miniproject\miniproject\urls.py", line 43 ] ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @kotmay can you copy and paste the code I wrote above to replace your `urlpatterns`.  You first had a missing `]` which you fixed, but did you also fix the missing `)`?  There should be *two* `))` after `namespace='blog'`.

Comment: I added another one ) and there was another error   File "C:\mysite\site\miniproject\miniproject\urls.py", line 31, in include
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
NameError: name 'ImproperlyConfigured' is not defined

Comment: Add `from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured` to the top of your code in any file using `ImproperlyConfigured`.  It has to be imported @kotmay

Comment: "provide the namespace argument to include() instead." % len(arg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Passing a 3-tuple to include() is not supported. Pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name, and provide the namespace argument to include() instead.

Comment: @kotmay you are obviously using an outdated tutorial using features that are no longer being used in Django, or will be removed in future versions.  I've edited my answer to fix what I see in your code, but in the end you are likely to keep getting these types of errors if you don't use a good code editor, and find a more recent tutorial.  Best of luck.